# How can we execute regression steps in Cucumber+Java multiple times so as to read data from excel?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm

I am working on an automation project using Selenium and java in Cucumber framework and Gherkins. I actually want to pass test datas from an excel so as to test the scenarios multiple times with the test datas. I am able to execute the script for one set of data. But for multiple set I can't.  Also we are using page object concept. Is there any way to make my code capable of accessing multiple set of data from excel so as to test the application with different data sets?

Please note I am using java and not ruby..

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Cucumber "Scenario Outline" feature here without using excel.